# netstandard2.1 version of CancellationTokenRegistration.Unregister()

Tags: c#, .net

`netcoreapp3.0` and `netcoreapp3.1` offer a function `CancellationTokenRegistration.Unregister()` but it isn't available in `netstandard2.1`. Why is this? Is there any way to unregister in `netstandard2.1`?

The documentation simply says it's not available in 2.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration.unregister?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.1

The discussion here leads me to believe it's just not available in 2.1 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19827

Is there any workaround? Something similar I could do?

Comment: got any conclusion on this?

Comment: @bruno.almeida nope, sorry. Frankly I can't remember what I did to get around this, I think I made a private fork of the repository and just upgraded it from netstandard to netcoreapp ... which probably isn't right, but you know how it can be sometimes.

Comment: @bruno.almeida -- It was removed. To unregister, you dispose of the `CancellationTokenRegistration` by calling the `Dispose` method. When in doubt, check the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/Microsoft.Bcl/System.Threading.Tasks.v1.5/System/Threading/CancellationTokenRegistration.cs#L18).

Comment: @Andy thanks, feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @xandermonkey -- sounds good. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is old, but I would like to clarify what happened.

`CancellationTokenRegistration.Unregister()` was removed in favor of calling `Dispose` on the corresponding `Registration` instance.

If you'd like to see how it all works, check out [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/f461f1986ca4027720656a0c77bede9963e20b7e/Microsoft.Bcl/System.Threading.Tasks.v1.5/System/Threading/CancellationTokenRegistration.cs#L18).